# $_SESSION for users on forums or stackoverflow

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose that I have also coded a similar login form then issue the session by name via $_SESSION['name'] as follows

```
session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
            header("Location: login.php");
    }
```

then right on the same file (display.php) I also display a form to post a message to the administrator to tell him about how I feel such as

```
    <td>
         <form action="tellhim.php" method="POST">
          Title:<input type="text" col="30" name="comment_title"/><br/>
          Your feeling:<br/><textarea name="comment_content" col="10"></textarea><br/>
          <input type="hidden" name="postfeeling" value="TRUE"/>          
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
         </form>    
    </td>
```

that means, right after I click the button to submit my feeling I will be directed to tellhim.php. The problem then is that the session seems invalid right after the page is reloaded. Could someone help me out please ?

Answer (score 2):

You should `exit();` after `header()`

file `tellhim.php` needs that also:
    `session_start();`

AND the `session_id` has somehow to be added to `tellhim.php`, automagically like this:

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', TRUE);
ini_set('url_rewriter.tags', 'a=href,area=href,script=src,link=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry,form=post,form=action');
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use session start() before all the files that you want to use**

//login.php after login redirect to display.php

session_start();

//set session variable

$_SESSION['name'] = 'xxx';

//display.php

session_start();

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
        header("Location: login.php");exit;
}
```

{rest of the form code goes here}